# SOSL having discrepant results than SOQL for same operation

Tags: apex, soql, query, sosl, dynamic-sosl

We are performing SOQL and SOSL operation to find particular value on an object.
Please find below code:

```
    String searchCustomerMobileNo = '9999999999';

    Double mobileNo = Double.valueOf(searchCustomerMobileNo);

    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id,Mobile__c,Name FROM Account WHERE Mobile__c = :mobileNo limit 50000];
    System.debug(accList +'\n SIZE: '+accList.size());    

    Search.SearchResults searchResults = Search.find('FIND \''+searchCustomerMobileNo+'\'  IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING  Account(id, name , Mobile__c   )');    
    List<Search.SearchResult> searchResultlist = searchResults.get('Account');
    System.debug('searchResultlist : '+searchResultlist+'\n SIZE: '+searchResultlist.size());
```

**Result:**

**For SOQL --> SIZE: 414**

**For SOSL --> SIZE: 250**

Here both SOQL and SOSL are searching for same data but, results produced by both queries differ i.e. SOSL result contains less data than SOQL result.

Why such a discrepancy in results for same operations? 
Please provide an explanation for such a behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a 250 records limit per entity.

[This post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AqjJIAS) may be useful for you